# How can I get a woocommerce brand thumbnail attribute?

Tags: php, woocommerce, thumbnails

I want to display brand logos on all product pages.

I've uploaded the logos in the theme editor by going to products->attributes->brands...clicking on the sprocket allows one to upload a thumbnail image.

There are several plugins that can achieve the same thing, but there must be a way to retrieve the information of the brand thumbnail.

Comment: Are you using a plugin that allows to add thumbnails to attributes? By default WooCommerce allows adding thumbnails to "Categories" and not "Attributes".

Comment: I'm not using a plugin, but usng the method I described above I can attach a brand to a thumbnail....and then the code renders as a thubnail with a class "pa_brand"....pa reffering to an attribute

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the WooCommerce Brands plugin, the following code supports obtaining a brand thumbnail URL:

```
global $post;
$brands = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_brand' );
if ( $brands )
    $brand = $brands[0];
if ( ! empty( $brand ) ) {
    $thumbnail = get_brand_thumbnail_url( $brand->term_id );
    $url = get_term_link( $brand->slug, 'product_brand' );
    echo '<a href="' . $url . '"><img class="woocommerce-brand-image-single" src="'. $thumbnail . '"/></a>';
}
```

.. If you are looking up via a term ID, then the following code will also obtain the thumbnail URL:

```
$url = get_brand_thumbnail_url( $term->term_id, 'full' );
```